# Set javascript cookie in Magento 1.8

Tags: jquery, magento-1.8

I'm on a project made by others web developers, in magento.

I've found this ajax call:

```
$j.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ws/newsletter/register",
        data: "email=" + d,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (e) {
            if (e.status != "1") {
                showFormError(a, c, e.msg)
            } else {
                $j('#newsletter-validate-detail button[type="submit"].bot').after('<div class="newsletter-info">' + e.msg + "</div>");
                $j("#" + c).val("");
                $j("#advice-ajax-request-newsletter-validate-detail-input").remove()
            }
            $j('#newsletter-validate-detail button[type="submit"].bot').removeClass("btnLoading")
        },
        error: function (g, f, e) {
            showFormError(a, c, unavailableMsg)
        },
        failure: function (e) {
            showFormError(a, c, unavailableMsg)
        }
    })
```

Where are the location of this?
/ws/newsletter/register

There are no WS folder.